# How can I highlight duplicate lines?

Tags: font-lock

Here's what I have:

```el
(defun my-show-duplicate-lines ()
  (interactive)
  (highlight-lines-matching-regexp
   (concat "^"
           (regexp-quote
            (substring-no-properties
             (thing-at-point 'line) 0 -1))
           "$")
   font-lock-warning-face))
```

My intention is to add this to `post-command-hook` to find lines where I'm duplicating logic, but when I run the command a second time, it's ineffective (and the old font-locking is still in effect).

The second problem is caused by font-lock not refreshing itself.  I've tried adding a `(font-lock-mode -1) (font-lock-mode 1)` to the definition, but it was ineffective.

I have no idea why the command would be only good for one run, though.

Comment: Try wrapping the `highlight-lines-matching-regexp` inside `(let ((hi-lock-mode -1)) .. )`. I did that to solve the same problem: https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/cb0b4b49ac565102c8e7c9af3147ac319fbba1f1/setup-files/setup-visual.el#L347-L362

Comment: `unhighlight-regexp` can also be used. Regardless this feature is probably best implemented using a font-lock matching function that scans the buffer for duplicate lines and applies highlighting to them. This would handle unhighlighting automatically once there are no duplicate lines.

Comment: @kaushalmodi no such luck :( thanks though

Comment: @JordonBiondo I thought about that, but `highlight-lines-matching-regexp` must be applicable to this case -- it's almost a shoe-in. (Though I also thought about using overlays, but that's a concept I'm less familiar with.)

Comment: You could copy the content of the buffer into another buffer, then run `delete-duplicate-lines`, then diff two buffers.

Answer (score 5):

1. Take a look at `font-lock-keywords` after you have called your function. You will see that it just has the regexp for the first line as the regexp to fontify. All you did was to pick up a given line and put a regexp to match it into `font-lock-keywords` - so only dups of that line get highlighted. IOW, the regexp for that first line is hard-coded in `font-lock-keywords`.
2. Instead, you could use a `FUNCTION` in `font-lock-keywords`.  But I would just search the buffer for dups of each line, in turn, and not bother with `font-lock-keywords`.

Here is one quick solution.  It uses function `hlt-highlight-region` from the [**Highlight**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) library ([**`highlight.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el)), but you can use something else if you like.

```el
(defun highlight-line-dups ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((count  0)
        line-re)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (not (eobp))
        (setq count    0
              line-re  (concat "^" (regexp-quote (buffer-substring-no-properties
                                                  (line-beginning-position)
                                                  (line-end-position)))
                               "$"))
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char (point-min))
          (while (not (eobp))
            (if (not (re-search-forward line-re nil t))
                (goto-char (point-max))
              (setq count  (1+ count))
              (unless (< count 2)
                (hlt-highlight-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)
                                      'font-lock-warning-face)
                (forward-line 1)))))
        (forward-line 1)))))
```

And here is a version that works on (a) the active region or (b) the full buffer if the region is not active:

```el
(defun highlight-line-dups-region (&optional start end face msgp)
  (interactive `(,@(hlt-region-or-buffer-limits) nil t))
  (let ((count  0)
        line-re)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char start)
      (while (< (point) end)
        (setq count    0
              line-re  (concat "^" (regexp-quote (buffer-substring-no-properties
                                                  (line-beginning-position)
                                                  (line-end-position)))
                               "$"))
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char start)
          (while (< (point) end)
            (if (not (re-search-forward line-re nil t))
                (goto-char end)
              (setq count  (1+ count))
              (unless (< count 2)
                (hlt-highlight-region
                 (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)
                 face)
                (forward-line 1)))))
        (forward-line 1)))))
```

And if you want a *different face for each set of dups* then just bind a variable `face` in the `let`, and `setq` it to `(hlt-next-face)` next to where `line-re` is set, and replace `font-lock-warning-face` with `face`.  Option `hlt-auto-face-backgrounds` controls the faces used.

```el
(defun hlt-highlight-line-dups-region (&optional start end msgp)
  (interactive `(,@(hlt-region-or-buffer-limits) t))
  (let ((hlt-auto-faces-flag  t)
        count line line-re ignore-re)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char start)
      (while (< (point) end)
        (setq count    0
              line     (buffer-substring-no-properties (line-beginning-position)
                                                       (line-end-position))
              ignore   (and (not (string= "" line))  "[ \t]*")
              line-re  (concat "^" ignore (regexp-quote line) ignore "$"))
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char start)
          (while (< (point) end)
            (if (not (re-search-forward line-re end t))
                (goto-char end)
              (setq count  (1+ count))
              (unless (< count 2)
                (hlt-highlight-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))
                (forward-line 1)))))
        (forward-line 1)))))
```

Comment: I was actually just working on something that looks almost the exact same, function for function! One thing I would suggest is stripping the leading/trailing whitespace from the line's text and adding something like [ \t]* to the beginning and end of the regexp so lines at different indent levels still match.

Comment: @JordonBiondo: But that's not what the OP asked for. Anything is possible, but I took my cue from the question and the solution attempt: He apparently really wants to match exactly the line text, and starting at bol, i.e., not disregarding indentation or trailing whitespace. But yes, lots of variants are possible. Dunno how useful anything like this really is. I guess it depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: Well, my use case is to recognize where logic is being duplicated so I can try to optimize :) I'm sketching out an algorithm and using a formal syntax, so exact duplicates are more than possible.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, Sean. But if you do want to ignore leading and trailing whitespace, as @JordonBiondo suggested, then just do as he suggested: add a possible-whitespace prefix and suffix to the regexp.

Comment: I tried using your last function but when compiling the function definition I get `setq: Symbol's value as variable is void: hlt-highlight-line-dups-ignore-regexp`. How is this variable defined?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code here from the version that I added to library [`highlight.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el). I've fixed it now, replacing option `hlt-highlight-line-dups-ignore-regexp` by its default value, `"[ \t]*"`. So if you want the version that lets you customize the whitespace-to-ignore regexp then grab `highlight.el`.

Answer (score 1):

How about using overlay instead of font-lock?

```
;; https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/ov.el
(require 'ov)

(defun my-highlight-duplicate-lines-in-region ()
  (interactive)
  (if mark-active
      (let* (($beg (region-beginning))
             ($end (region-end))
             ($st (buffer-substring-no-properties
                   $beg $end))
             ($lines)
             $dup)
        (deactivate-mark t)
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char $beg)
          (while (< (point) $end)
            (let* (($b (point))
                   ($e (point-at-eol))
                   ($c (buffer-substring-no-properties $b $e))
                   ($a (assoc $c $lines)))
              (when (not (eq $b $e))
                (if $a
                    (progn
                      (setq $dup (cons $b $dup))
                      (setq $dup (cons (cdr $a) $dup)))
                  (setq $lines
                        (cons (cons $c $b) $lines)))))
            (forward-line 1))
          (mapc (lambda ($p)
                  (ov-set (ov-line $p) 'face '(:foreground "red")))
                (sort (delete-dups $dup) '<))))))
```

Make region, and then `M-x my-highlight-duplicate-lines-in-region`
You can clear all overlays by `M-x ov-clear`

Answer (score 0):

This is a little sketchy, but with some effort (see <kbd>C-h f</kbd>`ediff-buffers`<kbd>RET</kbd> for the info on the `HOOK` argument) you could make it display better / perform a better cleanup upon exiting the diff mode:

```
(defun my/show-duplicate-lines (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (unless (region-active-p)
    (setf beg (point-min)
          end (point-max)))
  (let ((copy (buffer-substring beg end))
        (original (current-buffer))
        (dupes-buffer (get-buffer-create (format "%s[dupes]" (buffer-name)))))
    (with-current-buffer dupes-buffer
      (erase-buffer)
      (insert copy)
      (delete-duplicate-lines (point-min) (point-max))
      (ediff-buffers original dupes-buffer))))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Improvement on answer above by Shingo Fukuyama.](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13122)

This version checks for duplicate lines in active region but if there is none, searches the whole buffer.

```
(require 'ov)
(defun highlight-duplicate-lines-in-region-or-buffer ()
(interactive)

  (let* (
    ($beg (if mark-active (region-beginning) (point-min)))
    ($end (if mark-active (region-end) (point-max)))
    ($st (buffer-substring-no-properties $beg $end))
    ($lines)
    ($dup))
  (deactivate-mark t)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char $beg)
    (while (< (point) $end)
      (let* (($b (point))
         ($e (point-at-eol))
         ($c (buffer-substring-no-properties $b $e))
         ($a (assoc $c $lines)))
    (when (not (eq $b $e))
      (if $a
          (progn
        (setq $dup (cons $b $dup))
        (setq $dup (cons (cdr $a) $dup)))
        (setq $lines
          (cons (cons $c $b) $lines)))))
      (forward-line 1))
    (mapc (lambda ($p)
        (ov-set (ov-line $p) 'face '(:foreground "red")))
      (sort (delete-dups $dup) '<)))))
```